# How to leave space in HTML

Tags: html, tags

I do know that HTML is insensitive to space. But what can I use to make empty spaces between words, or phrases. I have tried `<p></p>` such kind of tags, but the HTML automatically omit it.

Can somebody give me example codes?

Comment: try &nbsp;w&nbsp;o&nbsp;r&nbsp;d

Comment: &nbsp;  tip: html remove all spaces except one.

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`&nbsp;`](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm), aka a [Non-Breaking Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

> It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this `&nbsp;` occupies.

Comment: This works, though now my ASCII art has a TON of `&nbsp;` in it.

Answer (score 22):

```
&nbsp;
```

This will give you the space you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The "pre" tag defines preformatted text. It preserves both spaces and line breaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
 <html>
        <body>
            <pre>This paragraph will be      pre-formatted. 
I hope this helps! 
All spaces will                    be shown as it is in the original file.
            </pre>
        </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

As others already answered, `$nbsp;` will output no-break space character. 
Here is [w3 docs for `&nbsp` and others](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.2.1).

However there is other ways to do it and nowdays i would prefer using [CSS stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/). There is also [w3c tutorials for beginners](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss).

With CSS you can do it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p { word-spacing: 40px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World! Enough space between words, what do you think about it?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `white-space: pre`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<span style="white-space: pre">    My spaces   </span>
<br>
<span>     My spaces   </span>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answers. Please be sure to read all existing answers before providing your own, to ensure no duplication of content occurs.

Comment: I think this is not a duplication but the easiest inline solution to create a space.   I tried other solutions and I used my solution in my project. I believe people will appreciate this following one line.
.
<span style="white-space: pre">    My spaces   </span>

Comment: this seems like a good solution, I don't understand why it's been down voted.

Answer (score 2):

“Insensitive to space” is an oversimplification. A more accurate description is that consecutive whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines) are equivalent to a single space, in normal content.

You make empty spaces between words using space characters: “hello world”. I you want more space, you should consider what you are doing, since in normal text content, that does not make sense. For spacing *elements*, use CSS `margin` properties.

To get useful example codes, you need to describe a specific problem, like markup and a description of desired rendering.

Answer (score 2):

To add *non-breaking space* or *real space* to your text in **html**, you can use the `&nbsp;` character entity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either use literal non-breaking space symbol (yes, you can copy/paste it), HTML entity, or, if you're dealing with big pre-formatted block, use [`white-space` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for paragraph indent then you can go for 'text-indent' declaration in CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
 <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                p { text-indent: 50px; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>This paragraph will be indented by 50px. I hope this helps! Only the first line will be indented.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve white-space with `white-space: pre` CSS property which will preserve white-space inside an element. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 0):

After, or in-between your text, use the `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) extended HTML character.

- EG 1 :

  This is an example paragraph. `&nbsp;&nbsp;` This is the next line.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to leave blank space in **HTML** while editing the website just use `<br />` and copy-paste it under the last one and keep going like that until you have enough space. Hope it helps.